# How do I create Constructor Subscription in vNext Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am experimenting with a throwaway vNext application.  What I'm trying to do is create a dummy class called 'DataService' which will return some data, and then create objects which use DI to take an IDataService parameter as the constructor.

So my IDataService/DataService definitions are:

```
public interface IDataService
{
    DateTime Created { get; }

}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private DateTime created = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime Created
    {
        get { return created; }
    }

}
```

In my startup class I register this as a singleton:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<Data.IDataService, Data.DataService>();
        });
```

And in a class I created, I add the IDataService interface as a constructor dependency:

```
internal class Constraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    public Constraint (IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
    }
    public bool Match(....)
    {
       //call dataservice for match
    }
}
```

The class here with the constructor dependency is an IRouteConstraint which I'm trying to use to get dynamic routes in MVC - the final part of the startup class code is this:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "TestRoute", template: "{*constraints}", defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }, constraints: new { constraint = new Constraint() }); //<--- how to construct using DI?

        });
```

The issue is that the Constraint() class can't be created because it is missing the constructor.  All the examples show a Controller using DI and the instantiation of the Controller classes are handled by MVC so that is part of the 'automagic' we don't see at first glance.

So my question is:

1. How do I instantiate the 'Constraint' object so that DI provides the implementation of the DataService singleton?
2. Is my issue because I'm trying this in the Configure method in the UseMvc method, or is my problem more fundamental than that?

I figure I'm missing some way of getting DI to act as an object factory to provide my objects instead of trying to declaratively creating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to resolve your Constraint through the Dependency Injection, you'll need to register it, first:

```
services.AddTransient<Constraint>();
```

Once you have the IApplicationBuilder, you can access the services directly:

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<Constraint>();
```

Of course, if you don't want to add your `Constraint` type to the services list, you can still access the `IDataService` the same way.

This assumes you have `using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;` declared at the top of your Startup; given your other syntax, I believe that you do.

Comment: I have added that line, but I keep getting this exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'TestProject.Constraint' has been registered.
`
I have checked and rechecked the registration of the IDataService and I can't figure out what I have done wrong.  I have 1.0.0-beta3 build 22605.

Comment: OK I figured it out.  Your answer is slightly incorrect - you need to use GetRequiredService<IDataService>(); to get the instance of the  DataService object, and then pass that to the constructor of Constraint.  So it is : `var newConstraint = new Constraint(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDataService>());`

Comment: Ah, I thought you'd registered your `Constraint` with the services already. I updated my answer to show how to use the DI directly with your custom class.

Comment: I must have something wrong in my understanding.  I thought I needed to register the type of the constructor parameter, not the class with the constructor.  Do I have it upside down?  Do I need to register Constraint with the services, and not the IDataService?

Comment: Oh, no, you'll need to register IDataService, too. However, if you want to have the DI fully construct your object (you probably should), in the case of the default DI implementation, you'll need to register the class actually being constructed.

Comment: That seems strange - why can't the DI library recognise that the Constraint class just needs it's parameters injected? Why the need to add the Constraint class as a transient service, if the framework could just figure it out by itself?

Comment: This prevents the DI from trying to construct things that aren't intentionally injected; if, for instance, a `Guid` were added as a constructor parameter, you'd end up getting an error that it didn't know which constructor of `Guid` to use. In addition, many other DI containers require that a service is registered before it can be constructed.

Comment: how can I get the `IApplicationBuilder`? Other than in the startup class