# How to specify constructor when registrating class in asp.net 5 with default Dependecy Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Is there are possibility to instantiate class using `ASP.NET 5` default `Dependency Injection` when that class have constructor with parameters?

I would like to register `Repository` with constructor that accepts `connection_string`.

**UPDATE**

I think that I can rephrase the question. I would like to specify which constructor will be called when the class is being registered. Something similar that Autofac have.  Is that possible?

```
builder.RegisterType<ConfigReader>()
   .As<IConfigReader>()
   .WithParameter("configSectionName", "sectionName");
```

Comment: Take  a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897372/access-to-configuration-object-from-startup/28953315#28953315

Comment: I think your question is extremely close to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29897027/195653 - you can only really accept objects, though. You should look at the OptionsModel.

Comment: I am not sure if that is what I need. What I actually want is to choose specified constructor when the class is registered. Something like Autofac does `builder.Register(c => new ConfigReader("sectionName")).As<IConfigReader>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the out of the box DI container does not support parameter constraints. It is all or nothing.

If you want advanced features, you can switch to another DI container, like Autofac, that you already mentioned and that is supported in ASP.NET 5.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the ASP.NET team will add those features in the future or should we stick with 3rd party solutions?

Comment: Currently, we have no plan to add them.